# Simple barplot displaying voting of a county

Tags: r, bar-chart

I'm fairly new to R and making plots, so sorry about that. I have a dataset of the voting for counties and I want to make a barplot showing how many mandates each county voted for.

What I've done so far is to extract one row, which includes the name of the county and the number of mandates it voted for the different parties (which are headers).

```
Fylker    AP FRP H KrF SP
Ostlandet  3  2   2  0  1
```

Sorry for the bad display of code, whenever I paste the code, it looks really weird, despite indenting.

The data is called "Ostlandet" and is only 1 row. So as I tried to explain above, I want to make some sort of barplot out of this. The idea is to have the different parties on the x-axis and number of votes on y. I've tried this so far

```
ggplot(Ostfold, aes(x = Ostfold[1,])) +
  geom_histogram(binwidth = 20)
```

Which just gave me tons of errors.

I've also tried using barplot, but I just can't seem to figure this out.

Sorry, this is probably super easy, but I'm just getting into coding.

Comment: It sounds like you're looking for `barplot(Ostfold[1,])`. There's probably a ggplot equivalent.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have a few issues. First, there's no need for extracting rows. Second, the data are in "wide" format (mandates in columns) instead of "long format" (a column named "mandate" with values). Third, you want to plot counts so `geom_col()` is better than `geom_histogram()`.

The `gather()` function from the `tidyr` package will get your data from wide into long:

```
library(tidyr)
library(ggplot2)

Ostfold %>%
  gather(Mandate, Votes, -Fylker)
```

That should generate something like this:

```
     Fylker Mandate Votes
1 Ostlandet      AP     3
2 Ostlandet     FRP     2
3 Ostlandet       H     2
4 Ostlandet     KrF     0
5 Ostlandet      SP     1
```

You can pass that to `ggplot`:

```
Ostfold %>% 
  gather(Mandate, Votes, -Fylker) %>% 
  ggplot(aes(Mandate, Votes)) + geom_col()
```

Result for your one row:

[image]

For a dataset with multiple counties, you might want to add `+ facet_wrap(~Fylker)` to facet the plot by county, depending on how many there are.

Comment: Thank you so much! This will help a ton as I have a lot of similar plotting to do.